# software center almost empty in ubuntu 20.04.2LTS (only nine things here - where my 18.04.5LTS if full of stuff)?

Tags: software-center

when open software center (3.38.1) it is practically empty - only thing is some snap registration thing... what happened? My Ubuntu 18.04LTS Ubuntu Software Center has tons of cool stuff, and so does the one on my Lubuntu 18.04LTS...

when I try to register for snap store account via the software center, click continue after giving an email address, it just locks up... have to cancel to stop it. Not sure why the login/registration for snap store is even there :-|

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is EOL as being a *flavor* it came with only 3 years of life.  Why not look in a package manager tool; e.g. modern Lubuntu comes with Discover (software store) & Muon package manager; the LXDE releases of Lubuntu came with the same two tools too (just GTK versions).  I like `aptitude` myself (terminal based) but `synaptic` (which came with Lubuntu 18.04) may make more sense to you on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: my 18.04's are fine - it's the 20.04 that seems defunct or something...

Comment: OK - weird but apparently a semi-work-around:

Once I launch software center, I can right click on the launcher icon, click 'show details' and another copy of software center opens but is FULL of stuff... happy but confused!

Comment: I seem to be able to confirm, it's empty, I'm on stock Ubuntu 20.04.2 fresh install half-a-year old. To clarify, it's called "Ubuntu Software", right? I seem to have seen this issue since quite some time ago, but not paid much attention to it as I don't use it. Additionally I don't find your "show details" workaround. Ooops sorry, seems to be false alert? It's just **waiting for a network response**, and **there is no spinner to indicate it**? Though I still believe sometimes those web requests do not get a response and this might be part of the perceived issue.

Comment: YES - "Ubuntu Software"... and just right clicking the icon in the launcher gives three options: New Window, Remove from Favorites, and Show Details. Left clicking brings up the pretty much empty window, but if instead you right click then left click Show Details you get the full window with lots of goodies ;-)

Comment: BTW - Waiting for 'network response' results in just endless 'wait'... hours! It's 'locked-up' :-\

Comment: Hey The MAJOR! Can you please add a screenshot of the issue which you are facing in the question by [edit]ing it? And I am unable to understand which OS and version you are using. Paste the output of `cat /etc/os-release` in your question.

Comment: snap store registration per the Ubuntu Software Center window not an issue as ubuntu software center works fine with work around and I'm used to it. Never really worried about Snap Store registration, and no longer even care about it, but was concerned with where the Ubuntu Software stuff was... They'll fix Ubuntu Software Center in an update when they get around to it!

Comment: Levente seems to know that I'm talking about, just that Ubuntu Software Center didn't seem that important :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click, not left click, on the Ubuntu Software launcher icon, where your selections will be 'new window', 'remove form favorites', and 'show details' <= left click 'show details' and the Ubuntu Software center opens and is FULL of the great ubuntu stuff... ignore any 'unable to find details' message... Ubuntu Software center is a bit buggy, but I still like it!

I think ubuntu is phasing out the ubuntu software center for the more robust 'SNAP STORE' method ;-)

BTW - offering a bounty to get help is a rip off - if nobody answers you get no refund. Next time I'll offer something a bit more enticing like money or, well... you know!